# getting confirmation first from user in a Tag helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am new to Tag Helper.  I have this

```
<a href="#" asp-controller="products" asp-action="deleteitem" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
```

is it possible first get the confirmation of user and pass it controller/Action. for example

```
<a href="#" asp-controller="products" asp-action="deleteitem" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  onclick="DeleteProduct()">Delete</a>
```

for example if the result of deleteProduct is true the action takes place. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to achieve this, I write a simple demo here

```
<a  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id" id="a1"  onclick="DeleteProduct()">Delete</a>


//I am using windows.confirm here to simulate the event, 
//when click Ok the event is true, when click cancel the event is false

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function DeleteProduct() {
          let text = "Press a button!\nEither OK or Cancel.";
          if (confirm(text) == true) {
            var a = $("#a1").attr('href');
            window.Location(a);
          } else {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
}
```

**result**

[image]